# Redis is not saving PHP Session in Docker Container

Tags: php, docker, redis

I have been trying to achieve session handler between PHP and Redis. I have configured everything (as per my knowledge and understanding) and there is no error as such. But still, I am not able to see any sessions are getting generated in Redis for PHP code.

my PHP Code:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['count']=(isset($_SESSION['count']))?$_SESSION['count']+1:1; 
$json['time ']= date(' Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$json['ip ']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$json['count '] = $_SESSION['count']; 
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Php and Redis docker-compose.yml entries are below:

```
php:
    image: php:7.1-fpm-alpine
    build: './.setup/php/'
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
      - ./.setup/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./.setup/php/docker-php-ext-redis.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-redis.ini
    links:
      - redis:cacheserver
    networks:
      public_net:
        ipv4_address: ${PHP_IP}

redis:
    build: ./.setup/cache
    networks:
      public_net:
        ipv4_address: ${REDIS_IP}
    container_name: cacheserver
```

Dockerfile for PHP:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

RUN echo http://uk.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community/  >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --no-cache shadow curl vim zlib-dev autoconf g++ make re2c \
    && pecl install -o -f redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so \
    && pecl clear-cache
```

Dockerfile for Redis:

```
FROM redis:3.2-alpine

COPY conf/redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]

EXPOSE 6379
```

Content of php.ini and docker-php-ext-redis.ini:

```
extension=redis.so
```

I tried to put below entries into php.ini, however, it is throwing an error, as of now I commented them:

```
#session.save_handler = redis
#session.save_path = tcp://192.168.0.24:6379
```

Error:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'redis' - session
>   startup failed in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2

Redis.conf file only has below entry to receive a request from anywhere:

> bind 0.0.0.0

Now I dont know, what is the problem, most importantly, I am not getting how will they both communicate. In my docker-compose.yml file, I have configured a fixed network and configured a static IP for both.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: i sthere a reason you are giving a custom container_name?

Comment: @delboy - Just to link with the PHP and having a proper name of the container, so that I can connect with the container easily. No other reason, if there is any other way around, I am happy to implement that.

Comment: You can use the yaml key as the host name. so no alias or ip addresses, and you should be able to call `tcp://redis:6379`

Comment: I tried before what you suggested, when I uncomment them, I get an error: Warning: session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'redis' - session startup failed in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2. This is my current entries:

extension=redis.so
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = tcp://redis:6379

Comment: I commented only - session.save_handler = redis and tried again. This time I got this error:

Warning: session_start(): open(tcp://redis:6379/sess_32c32ed0698b3d57e72df4d9e274201e, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2

Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: tcp://redis:6379) in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2
{"time ":" 2018-05-04 16:04:20","ip ":"192.168.0.33","count ":1}